# How to know that provided device tokens are real?

Tags: c#, iphone

I'm developing server-side for IPhone app.
This app has ability to subscribe on events (push notifications).
Is it possible to know that provided devide token is real (to prevent spam)? I'm afraid that somebody can subscribe millions fake devices and my "push" service will be overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add another parameter ("secure" parameter if you will) to the iPhone App; when you register your iPhone in your server, the request may send an identifier parameter that **only you know**, this way before storing the new device token, you can check if the "secure" parameter is the correct one.